# Need help with variables like $current_dir, $user_host etc

Tags: zsh

I am pretty new to Linux so please bear with me here :)

I want to customize my shell prompt (in `zsh`). Right now it looks like this (not written by me):

```
PROMPT="${user_host} ${current_dir} ${rvm_ruby} 
%B$%b "
```

Now what are these variables `${user_host}` etc. called and where can I see a list of them such that I can include things like e.g. the current time in my prompt?

Answer (score 3):

The variables such as `${user_host}` can be set to desired values inside your `.zshrc` file.

For example adding the following lines in your `.zshrc`:

```
local USER_HOST="${_prompt_colors[4]}%n@%m"
local CURRENT_DIR="${_prompt_colors[5]}%~"
PROMPT="${USER_HOST} ${CURRENT_DIR}$ "
```

will give you a prompt like:

```
ron@ron ~$
```

The characters that start with `%` in the above codes are special 'escape' sequences that are used to specify different kinds of information. Within the PROMPT variable, any occurance of these `%` sequences are replaced by the information that they represent. In the above codes:

- `%n` represents username and is equivalent to `$USERNAME`
- `%m` represents the hostname up to the first `.`
- `%~` represents `$PWD`, but will do two types of substitutions. If a named dir `X` is a prefix of the current directory, then `~X` is displayed. If the current directory is your home directory, `$HOME`, just `~` is displayed.

Now, you have various options to show data/time:

- `%t` - Current time of day, in 12-hour, am/pm format.
- `%T` - Current time of day, in 24-hour format.
- `%*` - Current time of day in 24-hour format, with seconds.
- `%w` - The date in day-dd format.
- `%W` - The date in mm/dd/yy format.
- `%D` - The date in yy-mm-dd format.

So,

> `PROMPT="${USER_HOST} ${CURRENT_DIR}%t$ "`

will give a prompt like:

```
ron@ron ~9:11AM$
```

See 'Expansion of prompt sequences' in `man zshmisc` or have a look at [this](https://www-s.acm.illinois.edu/workshops/zsh/prompt/escapes.html) or [this](http://www.csse.uwa.edu.au/programming/linux/zsh-doc/zsh_13.html) for more options that are available.

Comment: If you like the answer, just click the little grey **☑** under the "0" now turning it into beautiful green.  If you do not like the answer, click on the little grey down-arrow below the 0, and if you *really* like the answer, click on the little grey checkmark *and* the little up-arrow...  If you have any further questions, just [ask another one](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask)!